# How to make first record with title "manager"? (LDAP)

Tags: php, ldap

I have a list with titles and last names.
For example:
Economist Brown
Manager Johns
Engineer Peterson

```
$result = ldap_search($ldap_connection, $ldap_base_dn, $search_filter);

if (FALSE !== $result){
   $entries = ldap_get_entries($ldap_connection, $result);
   for ($x=0; $x<$entries["count"]; $x++){

            //Last Name
            if (!empty($entries[$x]["cn"][0])) {
                $LDAP_FullName = $entries[$x]["cn"][0];
                if ($LDAP_FullName == "NULL"){
                    $LDAP_FullName = "";
                }
            }
            //Job Title
            $LDAP_JobTitle = "";

            if (!empty($entries[$x]["title"][0])) {
                $LDAP_JobTitle = $entries[$x]["title"][0];
                if ($LDAP_JobTitle == "NULL"){
                    $LDAP_JobTitle = "";
                }
            }    
    }     
}
```

Comment: ???????????????

Comment: What's the problem?